# Is it possible to store an NSMutableArray in an NSObject?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm having trouble finding any information if it can be done, to put an NSArray or NSMutableArray stored as a parameter in an NSObject.

Or, an NSMutableArray filled with NSObjects (which are the titles of the to-do list being made) populating a Table View's Table Cells and THAT NSObject has a particular NSMutableArray associated with that NSObject to populate the next Table View's Table Cells.

I am in the beginning stages of making an app basically like the [Clear App by Realmac software](http://realmacsoftware.com/clear), but I'm wanting to play around and improve upon it for my own use.

Any other suggestions on how to store the data? I will start by using SQLite and go from there.

Comment: I didn't get the idea of storing the array in NSObject !!

Comment: I have no clue, I am just wondering. I am still kind of green to Objective-C programming.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: What do you mean with a "parameter in an NSObject"? Objects may have properties or ivars.

Comment: I am making an app with a main table view filled with titles of various to-do lists. Then when a cell is touched it will take you to the next table view with has to-do list items associated with that list name...check out the clear app link and it will make sense.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Maybe what I mean to say is ivars?

Comment: Aside from some slightly weird side features, an instance of NSObject (and not some subclass) does not have any instance variables and hence cannot store anything.  To store something you either pick an existing class (like NSMutableArray) or define your own subclass of NSObject which contains the fields and methods you want.  (I suspect you don't yet have a clear understanding of classes and objects.)

Comment: Then, yes: an object (an instance of a subclass of NSObject) can have an ivar which is a NSArray or any other kind of object. It also can be a C primitive or a struct, a pointer, a C++ instance, a function pointer, a block, and possibly a few more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer to this question...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342182/how-to-use-nsobjects/14342399#14342399

Like I said in that answer. You do not "use" an `NSObject`. You create a subclass of `NSObject` that you can then populate with whatever data you want.